# API calls needing one object from the nest array

Tags: jquery

When I press the button to call to the API, on the website 20 articles come up. Im trying to figure out how to get only one to pop up

I've tried articles
Tried title
Did articles.Object

Any in site on how to make that happen is beyond grateful. No error messages. In the end I would like to know how to only get one article from the 20 that is coming up.

Comment: lang-jquery
$(document).on("click","#icon-vcard", function(){
$(".card-body").empty();
event.preventDefault;
var queryUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com,nytimes.com&apiKey=496e966f5c324e3080abd07b9111c5c3";
$.ajax({
url: queryUrl,
method: "GET"
 })
.then(function(response) {
var results = response.articles;
$.each(results, function(i, e) {
$('#newsDiv').append('<p>Title: ' + e.title + "</p>");
console.log(response);
});

   
  });
});

Comment: That is the code on how it looks now with no changes to get only one article to pull down

Answer (score 0):

By using `.each()` your code loop through articles and get each article data .. if you need just one so no need to use `.each()`

You can use `response.articles[0]` with `[index]` you can get the article number you want ..

<sup>index starts from 0 so 0 for first article and 1 for second .. so on</sup>

```js
$.ajax({
  url : "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com,nytimes.com&apiKey=496e966f5c324e3080abd07b9111c5c3",
  method : "get",
  success : function(response){
    console.log('Number of Aricles: '+response.articles.length);
    console.log('Title of first Article: '+ response.articles[0].title);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This beyond helps. Super life saver :D

Comment: Totally Welcome.. Have a great day :-)